# How to find a value within a string

Tags: html

so, I'm making a robot that plays snake, and I need to find the location of the food, which is stored in the element

```
<div id="snake-food-0" 
  class="snake-food-block" 
  style="width: 20px; height: 20px; left: 160px; top: 20px;">
</div>
```

and all I need from that is `left: 160px; top: 20px`. how could I create a command that would find those two values.

Comment: um...javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all the attributes of style by referencing the element as below

```js
var x=document.getElementById('snake-food-0')
//console.log(x.style)
console.log(x.style.top)
console.log(x.style.left)
```

```html
<div id="snake-food-0" class="snake-food-block" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; left: 160px; top: 20px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By accessing the *style* property:

```js
const food = document.getElementById('snake-food-0');

console.log(food.style.left, food.style.top);
```

```html
<div id="snake-food-0" class="snake-food-block" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; left: 160px; top: 20px;"></div>
```